# Smartsheet API Token Python search query

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

How can I get the rows based on column value? In simple words, how can we write a search query and get the rows from smartsheet using python sdk.
Like

get rows where status = "Complete"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no single action that will let you query Smartsheet in the manner you've described.

The following code will accomplish your goal, but please note: I'm no Python expert, so I imagine there's a much faster way to accomplish this in Python -- e.g., perhaps even by using a single statement to filter the collection of columns and then rows (instead of iterating through them like this code does).

```
sheetId = 3932034054809476

# get the sheet
sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheetId) 

# identify the column ID of the column you're wanting to query/filter by
col_id = 0
for col in sheet.columns:
    if col.title == 'Status':
        col_id = col.id
        break

# iterate through rows creating a collection of Rows that match specified criteria
rows = []
for row in sheet.rows:
    for cell in row.cells:
        if cell.column_id == col_id and cell.value == 'Complete':
            rows.append(row)

# print number of rows that matched criteria
print(str(len(rows)) + ' matched the specified criteria.')
print('')

# print json for matching rows
print('Here\'s the JSON for the matching rows:')
for row in rows:
    print(json.dumps(row.to_dict()))
    print('')
```

Comment: Thank you Kim, But this will return all the cell attributes values, I need only rowid and the columns that are present in the sheet.

Comment: Your question says you want to **get rows where status = "Complete"** -- which is what I've shown how to do. I'd suggest that you update your question to more specifically describe exactly the outcome you're seeking.

Comment: Thank you Kim, I could get the data I want from the result obtained.

Comment: Terrific -- nice work! Would you mind 'accepting' my answer (since it answered the question you asked)? Doing so will make others more likely to benefit from this info in the future. Thanks!